# Variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java

Here I am, thinking I know Java, and I get the error `Variable 'storage' might not have been initialized`. Here is my code:

```
public class RobbleSet {
    private final Set<Robble> storage; // Error occurs here

    public RobbleSet() {
        storage = new HashSet<Robble>();
    }

    public addRobble(Robble r) {
        storage.add(r); // Error occurs here too
    }
}
```

`storage` is initialized in the constructor. What gives?

Comment: You might want to check to make sure that that's the *only* constructor. If you have multiple constructors, then every one of them will need to initialize `storage`. Better yet, just write `private final Set<Robble> storage = new HashSet<Robble>();` to begin with, and you won't need to put it in a constructor. :-)

Comment: I definitely only have one constructor. Are there any technical differences (on the bytecode / execution level) of initialization at the field rather than in the constructor?

Comment: I just posted an answer -- and I see that you edited your question to say the same thing. Regarding the technical differences between initializing in one place versus the other: Not really. From what I understand, the difference will be transmitted from the source-code to the bytecode (since one version goes in the `init` method instead of in the constructor), but that shouldn't have any *real* effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*One* problem is that you're not declaring a return type for `addRobble`; you need to change this:

```
    public addRobble(Robble r) {
```

to this:

```
    public void addRobble(Robble r) {
```

I suspect that this is *the* problem — that your compiler thinks that `addRobble` is a misnamed constructor, so is complaining that it fails to initialize `storage` — but even if it turns out that it's not *the* problem, it's definitely *a* problem.

Comment: +1 I noticed that too, but I would have thought he'd see a different error in that case.

Answer (score 2):

`addRobble` doesn't have a return type so the static analyzer is picking it up as a constructor even though it isn't called `RobbleSet`. The proper code is as follows:

```
public class RobbleSet {
    private final Set<Robble> storage; // Error occurs here

    public RobbleSet() {
        storage = new HashSet<Robble>();
    }

    public void addRobble(Robble r) {
        storage.add(r); // Error occurs here too
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

storage is declared as final and hence the error.
For a final variable the values must be assigned in the constructor.
The error in addRobble is also due to same, you cannot modify the value of a final variable in any method other than constructor.

Comment: Hi, could you provide some code example to furnish your answer ? This would help the OP and others to better understand your answer ;)